# Why am I getting an incorrect vector when trying to find HingeJoint2D.anchor in world space?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the scene, I have a long chain of children that are connected via hinge to their parent. For my code, I need the position of the hinge anchors in world space, so I use:

```
public Vector2 hingeVector => hinge.anchor + (Vector2)gameObject.transform.position;
```

For the first hinge, that code gives the correct position. But for the second hinge this happens:

[image: anchor position I get (red) vs actual anchor (blue)]

The red point is the vector I get, the blue point is the actual position. As you can see, it's a somewhat small but still problematic difference.

Is there any way I can fix this? I couldn't find anything like this online.

Comment: My first guess is that the anchor point is a [0-1] range value and that it is then multiplied by the width of the object. Another thought is that you need to multiply the anchor point by the object's *rotation.*

Comment: Yes, rotation! That makes a lot more sense and would explain why (as you can see in the picture) the red vector is perfectly aligned with gameObject's horizontal position. Final variable is `hinge.anchor.Rotate(gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z) + (Vector2)gameObject.transform.position` which seems to always give the correct position. I'll mark it as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You need to add the object's rotation

The anchor values are *axis aligned* and aren't affected by rotation, but in order to calculate the anchor point in world space, knowing the transform's position, you need to rotate the anchor point values by the object's rotation *then* add it to the position:

```
Vector2 p = hinge.anchor.Rotate(gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z)
              + (Vector2)gameObject.transform.position;
```